# AFNetworking conditional serialization type

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

The following code works very well in most cases, but in case of expired token, I get a JSON response with the problem description/identification, instead of a Jpeg image.

If I set the rom.responseSerializer as an AFHTTPResponseSerializer (as it is bellow), the error condition (json) is not parsed correctly. And even worse, if I use an AFJSONResponseSerializer, I get an serialization erro when the response is an image.

How can I deal with this conditional serialization type in order to handle the error case correctly? Does AFNetworking have an elegant way to handle that?

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager* rom = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] init];
    rom.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    rom.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

    id params = @{ @"token": [UserTokenManager getToken], @"code": [photoIdx valueForKey:@"Code"],     @"photoExtension": [photoIdx valueForKey:@"extension"] };

    NSString *url = [[[QXURLProvider provider] methodBuscarFotoPrograma] absoluteString];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [rom POST:url parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation     *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSString* mimetype =  [operation.response MIMEType];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: responseObject];
        CGSize imgSize = image.size;

        NSLog(@"size = %f, %f", imgSize.width, imgSize.height);

        self.imageView.image = image;

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Erro happened : %@", error);

    }];
```

Comment: There's no way to deal with that right now. It's not good API design whoever provides the image. I'd just try..catch the serialization error and suppress it.

Comment: `NSLog()` the `NSData` `responseObject` returned and post the hex dump and the ASCII if you know how. Also the `NSLog()` `mimetype `.

Comment: The responseObject nsdata is a valid jpeg image or a json string depending on the cases I mentioned. I'm looking for a beautiful way to switch my serializer, or else deserialize it by my self. Is mimetype a good switch condition?

Comment: Assuming the mimetype is correct yes.